# Enforce table sorting

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is it possible to enforce table sorting for a given table or file in Emacs org-mode?

When I say "enforce" I mean the table should get sorted
automatically whenever it's realigned (such as when I hit `<TAB>`
or `C-c C-c`). I want it to be sorted alphabetically according to
the first row.

Is there some property I can set to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to "advice" functions you call by keys.
http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Advice.html

```
;; advise a functions called by <TAB>
(defadvice org-table-next-field (around auto-sort-advice)
  "Sort table alphabetically according to the first rows"
  (progn
    ad-do-it
    (let ((pos (point)))
      ;; to to the first column
      (goto-char (org-table-begin))
      ;; one can change SORTING-TYPE (?a ?A ?n ?N ?t ?T)
      (org-table-sort-lines nil ?a)
      ;; restore position
      (goto-char pos))))

(ad-activate 'org-table-next-field)
```

Comment: For some reason this just isn't working for me. The function you've written works, but I can't get any advice to work with `org-table-next-field` (or a couple other org-functions that I tried). I've even tried simple advices such as `(message "hi")`.

Comment: @BruceConnor I think `(interactive)` does not play well with `after` advice. I changed to around in the answer.

Comment: In my experiments, it seems that `org-table-sort-lines` *must* be called on a "real" cell of the column to be sorted *after* any table header and hline and it only sorts entries between hlines. It does nothing if it's called while point is on the header (which is the position that `org-table-begin` returns). This is org-version 9.0.5 (release_9.0.5-288-g4caad0).